# How to efficiently insert key-value from one list of dictionaries to another based on a common key-value pair in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, optimization

I have this big list of dictionaries in python. An example of which is below:

```
big_list_dictionary = [{
    'name': 'test = 1',
    'id': 1,
    'value': 30
},{
    'name': 'apple = 1',
    'id': 2,
    'value': 70
},{
    'name': 'orange = 1',
    'id': 3,
    'value': 10
},{
    'name': 'balloon = 1',
    'id': 4,
    'value': 20
},{
    'name': 'airplane = 1',
    'id': 5,
    'value': 40
}]
```

and I have a list of two dictionaries with their total values

```
total1 = [{
    'name': 'test',
    'total': 130
},{
    'name': 'apple',
    'total': 270
},{
    'name': 'orange',
    'total': 310
},{
    'name': 'balloon',
    'total': 420
},{
    'name': 'airplane',
    'total': 540
}]

total2 = [{
    'name': 'test',
    'total': 230
},{
    'name': 'apple',
    'total': 570
},{
    'name': 'orange',
    'total': 3210
},{
    'name': 'balloon',
    'total': 620
},{
    'name': 'airplane',
    'total': 940
}]
```

If you notice, the `name` in `total1` and `total2` is just slightly different than `big_list_dictionary` where `= 1` is omitted.

How can I add the total values from `total1` and `total2` to `big_list_dictionary` so that the final result looks like the following:

```
[{
    'name': 'test = 1',
    'id': 1,
    'value': 30,
    'total2': 230,
    'total1': 130
},{
    'name': 'apple = 1',
    'id': 2,
    'value': 70,
    'total2': 570,
    'total1': 270
},{
    'name': 'orange = 1',
    'id': 3,
    'value': 10,
    'total2': 3210,
    'total1': 310
},{
    'name': 'balloon = 1',
    'id': 4,
    'value': 20,
    'total2': 620,
    'total1': 420
},{
    'name': 'airplane = 1',
    'id': 5,
    'value': 40,
    'total2': 940,
    'total1': 540
}]
```

Currently, the way I'm doing it is very slow.

```
    for item in big_list_dictionary:
        for t1,t2 in zip(total1,total2):
            if t1['name'] in item['name']:
                item['total1] = t1['total']
                item['total2'] = t2['total']
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the extra characters are always `=1` then you can create an intermediate relation and then use the following code.

```
big_list_dictionary = [{'name': 'test = 1','id': 1,'value': 30},{'name': 'apple = 1','id': 2,'value': 70},{'name': 'orange = 1','id': 3,'value': 10},{'name': 'balloon = 1','id': 4,'value': 20},{'name': 'airplane = 1','id': 5,'value': 40}]

total1 = [{ 'name': 'test','total': 130},{'name': 'apple','total': 270},
{'name': 'orange','total': 310},{'name': 'balloon','total': 420},{'name': 'airplane','total': 540}]
total2 = [{'name': 'test','total': 230},{'name': 'apple','total': 570},{'name': 'orange','total': 3210},{'name': 'balloon','total': 620},{'name': 'airplane','total': 940}]


intermediate = {i['name'].split('=')[0].strip():i for i in big_list_dictionary}

for t1, t2 in zip(total1, total2):
    intermediate[t1['name']]['total1'] = t1['total']
    intermediate[t1['name']]['total2'] = t2['total']

print(big_list_dictionary)
```

Output

```
[{'name': 'test = 1', 'id': 1, 'value': 30, 'total1': 130, 'total2': 230},
 {'name': 'apple = 1', 'id': 2, 'value': 70, 'total1': 270, 'total2': 570},
 {'name': 'orange = 1', 'id': 3, 'value': 10, 'total1': 310, 'total2': 3210},
 {'name': 'balloon = 1', 'id': 4, 'value': 20, 'total1': 420, 'total2': 620},
 {'name': 'airplane = 1', 'id': 5, 'value': 40, 'total1': 540, 'total2': 940}]
```

**Benchmark**

`%%timeit -n10 -r10` with `big_list_dictionary`, `total1` and `total2` of length `1000` each. Length has been increased to show the efficiency.

This Solution

`513 µs ± 17.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)`

Your Solution

`91.6 ms ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)`

***This solution is faster. (`513 µs < 91.6 ms`)*** The difference between both the solutions will only increase as the length increases.

**Edit based on comments:**

I believe there are some elements in `test1` and `test2` that are not in
`big_list_dictionary`, as there is an assumption that `test1` and `test2` have the same elements in the same order, you can just iterate through one of the list and append if not found to `big_list_dictionary` and also add that to `intermediate`. This appends all the new dicts at the end of `big_list_dictionary`, adding at the end is faster than inserting at a random position. But if you do care about order, then I believe your solution is as good as it gets.

Disclaimer : I have not tested this part of the code as I dont have the input or output to check the desired behavior.

```
big_list_dictionary = [{'name': 'test = 1','id': 1,'value': 30},{'name': 'apple = 1','id': 2,'value': 70},{'name': 'orange = 1','id': 3,'value': 10},{'name': 'balloon = 1','id': 4,'value': 20},{'name': 'airplane = 1','id': 5,'value': 40}]
total1 = [{ 'name': 'test','total': 130},{'name': 'apple','total': 270},{'name': 'orange','total': 310},{'name': 'balloon','total': 420},{'name': 'airplane','total': 540}]
total2 = [{'name': 'test','total': 230},{'name': 'apple','total': 570},{'name': 'orange','total': 3210},{'name': 'balloon','total': 620},{'name': 'airplane','total': 940}]


intermediate = {i['name'].split('=')[0].strip():i for i in big_list_dictionary}


for t1 in total1:
    if t1['name'] not in intermediate:         
        temp_dict = {'name': t1['name'],'id': 0,'value': 0}
        big_list_dictionary.append(temp_dict)
        intermediate[t1['name']] = temp_dict


# insert rest of the answer from code above
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This looks great. I'm testing it out right now. so far it looks pretty fast. Currently running for 187000 items.

Comment: if it works, up vote and accept the solution

Comment: will do. I've already upvoted the solution. Will select as an answer soon as I get the results.

Comment: sure @Kuni, also for my curiosity, can you let me know how much of a time difference you got once you run?

Comment: sure .. i'm running into other issues which is not related to your solutions. Once I fixed those and get the full results, then I can add the time difference.

Comment: just a quick question if it's possible to answer. If I add `if t1['name'] not in intermediate:
        print(t1['name'])
        intermediate[t1['name']]={
            'name': t1['name'],
            'id': 0,
            'value': 0
        }` in `for loop`, why doesn't `big_list_dictionary` show the addition? How can I make sure the new dictionary is also inserted in `big_list_dictionary`? I know it's outside of the question, but I'd really appreciate it if you don't mind answering this.

Comment: The way that I did this like so: `if t1['name'] not in intermediate:
        print(t1['name'])
        big_list_dictionary.insert(index,{
            'name': t1['name'],
            'id': 0,
            'value': 0
        })
        intermediate = {i['name'].split('=')[0].strip():i for i in big_list_dictionary}`. Not sure if there's a better way to do this

Comment: @Kuni the formatting is messed up in comments, would you mind linking to a pastebin or dpaste?

Comment: to answer your question as to why the changes are not shown, `intermediate` is a dict that has reference to the dicts in `big_list_dictionary`, since a dict is a mutable type, changing the values will change all the references, that is how the solution works, but what you are doing creates a new dict in `intermediate` with the key `t1['name']` this is not referenced in the `big_list_dictionary` and hence the changes are not propagated, if you dont understand I would explain it in a different way

Comment: the second comment would make more sense to me after seeing a formatted code, as I have no idea where `index` is from

Comment: yeah .. sorry I missed that part. I had `for index, (t1,t2) in enumerate(zip(total1,total2)):`. But the solution is working now.

Comment: were you able to understand the explanation I gave?

Comment: Yes, I understand the explanation. But I believe you're okay with the "second-comment-solution"? It seems to be working

Comment: And, sorry about the unformatted text. Here's the pastebin https://pastebin.com/Yk6Dr377

Comment: @Kuni I am not sure, I didnt put much thought into that, let me check and get back

Comment: I have checked and from what I understand, there are some keys that are in `total1` and `total2` that are not there in `big_list_dictionary`, so you are adding them to `big_list_dictionary`? is this is correct?

Comment: dude!! Is there a way to upvote you like multiple times and select this as answer again? Wow!! You're super amazing!! I bow to thee... !!

Comment: thank you for your kind words :D, glad my code helped you achieve something

Comment: I just realized this is my 100th answer

Comment: That's a century. If you know the sports of Cricket, that's something to celebrate for!!